# Java: WSDL web service wsimport, do I need to re-run wsimport of I change the @WebService class code in the webservice server

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, glassfish, wsimport

I'm building a webservice with a java client and a java webservice on Glassfish running on Windows Werver 2012.

This is my @WebService class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class ProductCatalog {

    public List<String> getProductCategories(){
     List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
     categories.add("Books");
     categories.add("Music");
     categories.add("Movies");

     return categories;
   }
}
```

On the *client side* to create the stub method I use *wsimport* conversion that is in java to generate the required java source files comming from the WSDL xml issued by the WS.

What I have noticed is that, if I add a cetgory to to the list:

```
     //...code
     categories.add("Books");
 categories.add("Music");
 categories.add("Movies");
 categories.add("Pens");
     //...code
```

I get from the client side the updated arraylist: Book,Music,Movie + "Pens"

- but if I add a new method to che class, the method is not visible to
  the client side, how come?
- Is it because I need to run WSIMPORT on the WSDL file again and
  recompile the client side?
- If the above is true, is there a way to    avoid the WSIMPORT
  class/source file generation everytime there is a    change in the
  Serverside/webservice code?

thanks Luther

Answer (score 1):

Web service is typically used for inter process communication and hence requires a strong contract for operating the service. The WSDL provides a means of such a contract. Hence, you will need updated WSDL every time there's a change in the contract.

However, there's still an option where WSDL is not required for service invocation. It can be achieved using dynamic invocation (https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Develop_a_JAX-WS_Client_Application.html). There are pros and cons. Depending on your use case, this may be a solution.

Comment: Is it possible that dynamic invocation will compromise performance by "substantially" slowing the soap communication process?

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this is to write your business logic in a separate class and invoking that method in your service class.Take out that getProductCategories() method into other class and create instance of that class and call the method.So when you add new method in business class,no need to change wsdl or anything.But don't change the method signature and parameters.